# Wordpress cron don't add content to new post, but manual start working fine

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm testing php plugins in Wordpress. I have created one which working correctly only when I run function manually. (logged in as Admin). Problem starts when script is called via cron. Cron is created right, post in wordpress is correctly created, image is correctly downloaded but content of the wordpress post is only empty img html tag "< img >". I thought that is because crontab is not logged user and there is some wordpress restriction but cannot find the issue.
Here is the function.

BTW all variable are filled, function is working when I run it via doJob() in php.

1) Input is array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => "Title1"
        [content] => "http://example.com/image.jpg"
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => "Title2"
        [content] => "http://example.com/image2.jpg"
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => "Title3"
        [content] => "http://example.com/image3.jpg"
    )
```

2) Function doJob() 
This function just iterate on input array, create new wordpress post, download image, and update content of the post with "

```
 public function doJob() {

        if ( ! function_exists( 'post_exists' ) ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );

        }

        $c = $this->getData(1);



        foreach ($c as $key => $value) {

            if(($value['title'] != '') or ($value['content'] != '<img>') or ($value['content'] != '')){




            $my_post = array(
                'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $value['title'] ),
                'post_content'  => '',
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_category' => array(94)
            );


            if(!post_exists ($my_post['post_title'])){


                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );


                // Add Featured Image to Post
                $image_url  = $value['content']; 
                $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
                $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url); 
                $filename   = basename($image_url); 


                if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
                $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
                } else {
                $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
                }

                $contentImage = $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $filename;


                file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );


                // Check image file type
                $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

                // Set attachment data
                $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                );

                // Create the attachment
                $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

                // Include image.php
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

                // Define attachment metadata
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

                // Assign metadata to attachment
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

                // And finally assign featured image to post
                set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

                $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id) );


                $updateContent = array(
                  'ID'           => $post_id,
                  'post_content' => '<img src="'. $feat_image .'"">',
                  'post_author'   => 1,

                );

                wp_update_post( $updateContent );

            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Thank you for any help.
RogueCZ

Comment: I found what causes it, but I do not know how to fix it. Cron running as non admin user which don't have rights to update post content.

Answer (score 0):

There was the problem, I just make mistake with double "" in UpdateContent Array

```
$updateContent = array(
              'ID'           => $post_id,
              'post_content' => '<img src="'. $feat_image .'"">',
              'post_author'   => 1,

            );
```

Thank you for support :)